# Bad Address in NSOutlineView's delegate and data source

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, exc-bad-access, nsoutlineview

I implemented a class to study providing NSOutlineView's delegate and data source.

What I wanted to show in the outline view is like this:

**|-------Column 0-----------------|------------Column 1-----------------------|

 - Living Room 　　　　|　Description for Living Room

　+ Living Room - 1　　|　Description for Living Room - 1

　+ Living Room - 2　　|　Description for Living Room - 2

 - Bedrooms　 　　　　|　Description for Bedroom

　+ Bedroom - 1　　　|　Description for Bedroom - 1

　+ Bedroom - 2　　　|　Description for Bedroom - 2

　+ Bedroom - 3　　　|　Description for Bedroom - 3

 - Dining Rooms　　　 |　Description for Dining Rooms

　+ Table 　　　　　　|　Description for Table**

---

And I implemented the delegate and dataSource methods. But **the problem is:** when the outline view is displayed for the first time, it goes well. But as I expand one of them, as long as whose child count is greater than 1, things went wrong. **Sometimes I got a strange outline view item object, sometimes I got bad address.**

**I am very sorry that I have to post all my codes here. But I could not find where goes wrong...**

**My question is:**
Could anyone copy my codes and build it? I wonder whether you also got the bad address issue from my codes. And if so, could anyone please find out where goes wrong? I could not locate the problem, and therefore do not know how to fix that.

Thank you!

---

The delegate and dataSource class is implemented as below (using ARC, and all item for the cell are set to an NSString object):

```
@implementation AMCTreeData
{
    NSTableColumn *_titleColumn;
    NSTableColumn *_descriptionColumn;
}

/**********/
/* initialize the outline view */
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    /* get column object */
    _titleColumn = [[_outlineView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0];
    _descriptionColumn = [[_outlineView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:1];

    /* set a new text template */
    ImageAndTextCell *newCellTemplate = [[ImageAndTextCell alloc] init];
    [newCellTemplate setEditable:NO];

    [_titleColumn setDataCell:newCellTemplate];
    [_descriptionColumn setDataCell:newCellTemplate];
}   

/**********/
/* determine whether a line should be expanded */
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    if (!item)
        return YES;
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Living Room"])
            return YES;
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Bedrooms"])
            return YES;
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Dining Rooms"])
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}


/**********/
/* determine member of each groups */
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    AMCPrintf("==============\n\tCheck child amount for %s", [[item description] UTF8String]);

    if (!item)
    {
        /* top item */
        return 3;
    }
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Living Room"])
            return 2;
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Bedrooms"])
            return 3;
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Dining Rooms"])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}   

/**********/
/* determine a cell item's content */
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
{
    if (!item)
    {
        /* continue */
    }
    else if (![item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        /* Unsupported */
        AMCDebug(@"Object %@ ??? What the ...", item);      /* Yep, it may go here */
        return @"";
    }


    /* First column */
    if (tableColumn == _titleColumn)
    {
        AMCPrintf("Require object value (0) for \"%s\"", [[item description] UTF8String]);

        if (!item)
            return @"TOP_0";
        else
            return item;
    }
    /* second column */
    else if (tableColumn == _descriptionColumn)
    {
        AMCPrintf("Require object value (1) for \"%s\"", [[item description] UTF8String]);

        if (!item)
            return @"TOP_1";
        else
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Detailed for %@", item];
    }
    else
    {
        AMCPrintf("!!! Unsopported column %s", [[item description] UTF8String]);
        return nil;
    }
}


/**********/
/* determine whose child a item is */
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    AMCPrintf("Require child for %s in Line %ld", [[item description] UTF8String], index);

    if (!item)
    {
        id ret;

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
            ret = @"Living Room";
                break;
            case 1:
                ret = @"Bedrooms";
                break;
            case 2:
                ret = @"Dining Rooms";
            break;

            default:
                ret = nil;
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Living Room"])
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Living Room - %ld", index + 1];
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Bedrooms"])
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room - %ld", index + 1];
        else if ([(NSString*)item isEqualToString:@"Dining Rooms"])
            return @"Table";
        else
            return nil;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

---

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @user1118321 When the outline view with the dataSource coded above was expanded, exception happened: bad address 0x0.

Comment: @user1118321 Perhaps it IS STUPID to post my codes here... Sorry. I would write another data source class and try again.

Comment: It's not stupid at all. You definitely *should* post your code. But you still haven't asked a question. Is your question about why the bad address is happening? Is your question how you should debug it? What is it you want help with?

Comment: @user1118321 Ah, I see. I modified my question a bit, is it clearer now? Actually I am quite panicked by the "bad address" exception. Because I could not find in which step the application went wrong, even by using "step by step", as the exception was not raised during my written codes. Therefore what I searching for help for was finding out the bug and fix it.

Comment: I'm unable to build the code, as there's a syntax problem with it. I think the issue is a missing "}" on the 3rd if statement in `-outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:`.

Comment: @user1118321 I removed it, now should be OK. In my original project, All if-else blocks have "{}" pairs. But I deleted some here in order to save the page length but I missed one :)